# trouble using SMLNJ in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, sml

After I start and execute this great program, I expected to see the output `val it = 2 : int`

```
$ sml
Standard ML of New Jersey v110.74 [built: Fri Dec  7 10:09:50 2012]
- 1+1
= 
= 
=
```

However, I see only equals, and when I execute the same program in emacs, I get the same behaviour. sml never prints the result.

I am working in last version of ubuntu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot the semicolon.

```
- 1 + 1;
val it = 2 : int
```

Comment: this was my first program in standard ML :)

Comment: No problem. I'm sure I've done the same thing at one time. :)

Answer (score 2):

You need a ; at the end of the line